# Player Movement in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

So I am new at Unity and I am following a YouTuber named Brackeys but when I execute his code for movement of the character my character doesn't go forward or backward it does go Left and Right but in super speed.
I am new at this so I don't know much about this.
Here is the code :

```
using UnityEngine;
```

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Rigidbody rb;

private float forwardForce = 2000f;  
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;  

void FixedUpdate()
{

    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))  
    {

        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))  
    {

        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (rb.position.y < -1f)
    {
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well there is no handling of w or s keys if you're hoping to use those keys to go forward and back.

Comment: So how can we move forward and backward ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing here is movement along z axis.

```
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))  
    {

        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("s"))  
    {

        rb.AddForce(0, 0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks it is working indeed I tried it before but I think my code had some problems but your code is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

change the sideways force if you dont want it to go super speed:

```
> public Rigidbody rb; private float forwardForce = 2000f;  // This is
> how fast the player goes forward public float sidewaysForce = 500f; 
> //Change the number here to something lower.
```

//Add this to go forward and backward

```
if (Input.GetKey("w"))  
    {

        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("s"))  
    {

        rb.AddForce(0, 0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```